# Input another encryption into cbc mode

Tags: java, encryption, des

Current I am using the block encryption DES to do CBC, I would like to include an option for user to use other block cipher such as Tiny Encryption. The output for tiny encryption is different from the DES classes i used hence i am unable to add this in. Anyone can give a little help here?

```
private static int delta = 0x9E3779B9; /* a key schedule constant */
public void code(int[] v, int[] k) { 
int y=v[0], z=v[1], sum=0, n=32; 
int k0=k[0], k1=k[1], k2=k[2], k3=k[3]; /* cache key */
while (n-- > 0) { 
 sum += delta; 
 y += ((z << 4) + k0) ^ (z + sum) ^ ((z >>> 5) + k1); 
 z += ((y << 4) + k2) ^ (y + sum) ^ ((y >>> 5) + k3); 
 } 
 v[0]=y; v[1]=z; 
 }
```

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

```
private static void cbc(byte [] raw_key, PrintStream ofstream) {
    byte [] cbc_ciphertext = null;
    byte [] IV = CryptoUtil.getIV();
    try {
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(raw_key, "DES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance ("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        /* increment in 8-byte blocks through plaintext */
        for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i += 8) {
            byte [] block = CryptoUtil.getBlock(plaintext, i);
            if (i == 0)
                cbc_ciphertext = c.doFinal(CryptoUtil.xor (IV, block));
            else {
                ciphertext = CryptoUtil.append(ciphertext, cbc_ciphertext);
                cbc_ciphertext = 
                    c.doFinal(CryptoUtil.xor(cbc_ciphertext, block));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    ciphertext = CryptoUtil.append (ciphertext, cbc_ciphertext);
    ciphertext = CryptoUtil.append (IV, ciphertext); 
    // ciphertext now has chained encrypted cipher blocks
    ofstream.print(CryptoUtil.encode(ciphertext));
    System.out.println("encrypted ciphertext (DES/CBC) to " +
                "ciphertext.txt");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: question is..rather than using DES encryption class, how can I implement tiny encryption to replace the current DES class

Comment: I haven't gone through the code completly, but the first thing that caught my eye in your cbc implementation is: Why are you trying to implement your own CBC mode? Why don't you use "DES/CBC/NoPadding" as cipher moder?